# Java generics. В чем разница между wildcard(<?>) и parameterized types(<T>)?

Tags: java, generics, wildcards

`T` - тип, который произволен и при стирании трансформируется в `Object` - суперкласс всех классов в **Java**.
`?` - по идее то же самое или нет?
Я не могу понять, зачем нужен метасимвол `?`. В Шилдте приведен пример с суммированием: если использовать `T`, то нельзя сравнивать между собой `Double` и `Integer`, а если `?`, то можно. До конца не могу понять разницу. А также есть ли разница, например, `<T extends Number>` и `<? extends Number>`? Ведь если они были бы одинаковы, то смысл вводить их в язык...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Документация

Переменная типа указывается в ***объявлении*** обобщенного класса, интерфейса, метода или конструктора. После этого ее можно использовать в качестве типа в теле этого класса, интерфейса, метода или конструктора. Переменная типа может называться как угодно (`T`, `X`, `MyAwesomeType`).

Аргументы типа используются при ***использовании*** типа. Например, при объявлении переменной или аргумента метода. Аргументы типа могут являться ссылочными типами или символами подстановки.

Можете почитать об этом в спецификации языка Java:

- [§4.4. Переменные типа.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)
- [§4.5.1. Аргументы типа и символы подстановки.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

### Пример

> В Шилдте приведен пример с суммированием: если использовать T, то нельзя сравнивать между собой Double и Integer, а если ?, то можно

Давайте попробуем разобрать пример. Насколько я понимаю используется код вроде этого:

```
class Stats<T extends Number> {

    T[] nums;

    Stats(T[] o) {
        nums = o;
    }

    double average() {
        return Arrays.stream(nums).mapToDouble(n -> n.doubleValue()).sum() / nums.length;
    }

    boolean sameAvg(Stats<?> ob) {
        return average() == ob.average();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stats<Integer> iob = new Stats<>(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
        Stats<Double> dob = new Stats<>(new Double[]{0.5, 1.25, 4.25});
        if (iob.sameAvg(dob)) {
            System.out.println("are the same.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("differ.");
        }
    }
}
```

Во-первых, `?` нельзя указать в качестве переменной типа. Если объявить класс так:

```
class Stats<? extends Number> {
```

, то возникнет ошибка компиляциии так как мы объявляем переменную не указывая ее названия.

Во-вторых, мы не можем использовать `T` для аргумента типа `sameAvg`. Если сделать так:

```
boolean sameAvg(Stats<T> ob) {
    return average() == ob.average();
}
```

, то не скомпилируется следующая строка

```
if (iob.sameAvg(dob)) {
```

Дело в том, что `T` — это ***один*** конкретный тип для всего класса. Для переменной `iob` это `Integer`, соответственно ее метод `sameAvg` принимает только `Stats<Integer>` и не может принять `Stats<Double>`.

Нам же здесь нужно ***два*** типа. Один из них `T`, он используется внутри класса. Другой: для аргумента `ob` в методе, чтобы класс мог взаимодействовать с объектами `Stats` других типов. Называть этот второй тип нам никак не нужно поэтому вместо него можно указать символ подстановки

```
boolean sameAvg(Stats<?> ob) { //любой Stats, не только Stats<T>
```

Второй тип можно объявить и явно в качестве переменной типа для метода `sameAvg`:

```
<U extends Number> boolean sameAvg(Stats<U> ob) {
     //в примере выше T - Integer, U - Double
     return average() == ob.average();
}
```

Повторюсь, здесь в этом нет необходимости, т.к. `U` не используется внутри метода. В других случаях может понадобится именно такое объявление, а не символ подстановки. Почитайте [Java: bounded wildcards or bounded type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486689/java-bounded-wildcards-or-bounded-type-parameter)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов Пожалуйста! Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Если тема исчерпана, то отметьте ответ как правильный (слева от ответа должна быть серая галочка — нажмите на нее).

Comment: То есть получается, что множество значений, которое задается <T> вложено, с точки зрения теории множеств, в <?>.

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов Нет, по крайне мере ненапрямую. Метод объявляет что принимает `Stats` с любым (`?`) параметром. Просто, сам `Stats` ограничивает количество значений `T`. Например, `Stats<String>` просто не получится объявить нигде. Метод полагается на это.

Comment: Смотрите, Вы написали, что T - конкретный тип, то есть как бы получается, что Stats String - класс, который оперирует только со String и только. А вот <?> позволяет как бы создать класс, в который можно запихнуть все, что твоей душе угодно. Это просто как я, юный java'ист вижу для себя, а не как на самом деле там все создается.

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов Вроде похоже на правду :)

Comment: Почему-то ни в каких других источниках не обозначено настолько же явно, что T - это про объявление дженериков, а ? - про их использование. Видимо, это предполагается чем-то очевидным, но для меня такое объяснение - как раз то, чего не хватало.